# From VS2010 in Windows 7 using Directory.Delete(path) from the VS debugger

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, permissions

From VS2010 in Windows 7 using Directory.Delete(path) from the VS debugger.
I have full admin rights to my machine.

I basically ran

```
Directory.Delete(path)
```

Not only did it not delete the folders, but now when I try to go and delete them manually I get

[image]

No matter what I do, it will not let me delete the path any more. If my program tries to delete it, I get a UnathorizedAccessException.

What's going on here?

**EDIT**:

I've tried deleting from Windows explorer and from a command box running as administrator.
I don't actually see what else there is to do.

Comment: Can you expand on "No matter what I do" ? What have you tried?

Comment: This should help: [Win 7: Access denied to delete folder](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/win-7-access-denied-to-delete-folder/d2264e35-670e-467d-b3e4-3a5610aa5474)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in cmd:

```
attrib "MyFolder" -R -A -S -H
```

You may have accidentally marked folder as a system folder in your application. Also try restarting the computer after doing this. Also you can right click the folder and go to the security/permissions tab and see if you (the admin) has all the rights for that folder (try marking all boxes). They sometimes get scrambled during file operations.

Comment: You can search for windows explorer take ownership to explain what's really happening.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you are trying to delete the folder from an application, here is a code snippet that allows you to clear all file system attributes and then delete the file. the code snippet is not mine I took it from somewhere else but I cant remember where.

```
  private static void DeleteFileSystemInfo(FileSystemInfo fsi)
    {
        fsi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        var di = fsi as DirectoryInfo;
        if (di != null)
        {
            foreach (var dirInfo in di.GetFileSystemInfos())
                DeleteFileSystemInfo(dirInfo);
        }
        fsi.Delete();
    }
```